# chrome_url_overrides not working with incognito new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've just learned about chrome extension, and I created an app to change the new tab page of chrome. In the app, I use "chrome_url_overrides": {"newtab": "new.html"}. But I found this doesn't work in incognito mode (the new 
Incognito tab is in default, not the new.html), although I turned on option "Allow in incognito". Someone can tell me how to fix? 
Thanks

**UPDATE:** My source code [here](https://github.com/Somethings1/newTab)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Sounds like either a bug or a feature in Chrome. You can report it on https://crbug.com

Comment: @Ibo I think I dont know what to show. Can you please specify it?

Comment: you said you have created an app, you need to deploy a demo version of it and let people interact with it and see where the problem is

Comment: I've just updated the github link of my app. Please check it out

Answer (score 2):

From the [override docs page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override):

> New Tab pages cannot be overridden in incognito windows.

I also tried sneaking around that by using stuff like `chrome.tabs.onCreated` and `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, but none of it worked.

I believe they don't want you to mess with the informational message about how Incognito works that normally appears on the new tab page.